# Google Cloud Dataflow: Can't parse proto using TextIO.Read

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Here's my code

```
PCollection<MyProto> pCollection = p.apply(TextIO.Read.from(
            "gs://my_bucket/*")
            .withCoder(Proto2Coder.of(MyProto.class)));
```

but this fails with the error

```
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
```

The file when downloaded locally parses fine.

I've also tried to do the same thing by using a StringUtf8Coder and ByteArrayCoder, but no dice.

any help? Should I not be using TextIO? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextIO splits the file into lines and applies the coder to each line. Naturally, that doesn't work well with formats that are not line-based. I suppose that your files contain a single serialized proto each, correct? In that case you have 2 options:

- Create your own Source and Reader classes (see [generic documentation on creating sources and sinks](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/sources-and-sinks)) by subclassing [FileBasedFormat](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource).
- Treat the act of processing all your files as a ParDo - create an in-memory PCollection containing the filenames to process (using `Create.of()`) and pipe it through a ParDo that takes a filename and parses the file as a protobuf; then pipe to the rest of your pipeline.

The second is easier but the first will work better if you have really a lot of files.

Comment: Is there a reason there's no generic `FileIO.Read` source?

Comment: We have protobufs. It could also be JSON, for example.

Comment: There are too many different file formats and the hypothetical FileIO can not possibly explicitly support all of them. I feel like I'm not understanding your question. Perhaps do you mean that FileIO.Read would simply parse the entire contents of each file as a single byte array, which could be in any format, and then apply a user-supplied parser to this byte array? (e.g. converting the byte array to a protobuf, or to JSON, etc) That would make sense but I'm not sure that's what you mean?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I mean. A Google Cloud Storage file-based source where the atomic unit is the file (as a byte array). Thanks!